# What can you do the System.IO namespace and its classes (fileinfo, directory etc.)? (simple terms)

Tags: c#, file, directory, fileinfo, system.io.file

I'm taking a C# course on Udemy. In this course, there is a section where they discuss "working with files". He teaches us how to use the .IO namespace and its classes, however I don't know what it does, how it can be used, and when it should be used (examples of real world applications).

Can someone please explain to me what the .IO namespace and it's classes (like fileinfo) are used for, and when we can apply it (in simple terms(I'm only a beginner)). Thank you!

Comment: Well, all of the regular file IO code is in that namespace, so if you want to work with files it's almost essential.

Answer (score 1):

The [`System.IO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io) namespace contains types for working with I/O. So, whenever you want to input something or output something, you will almost certainly use it.

And since pretty much everything will at some point either need some input or provide some output, if only for debugging purposes, the real-world applications of `System.IO` is "pretty much every .NET code ever written".

For example, almost every programmer will, at some point in their life, have written the following program:

```cs
class HelloWorld
{
    static void Main()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Well, [`System.Console.WriteLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline#System_Console_WriteLine_System_String_) simply delegates to [`System.IO.TextWriter.WriteLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.textwriter.writeline#System_IO_TextWriter_WriteLine_System_String_), so whenever you have written a Hello World program, you have used System.IO.